# If Pilot wave theory turns out to be the correct way of interpreting quantum mechanics what are the implications?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bohmian-mechanics

I've read a few articles on Pilot Wave theory. Part of the theory describes how particles have a deterministic path and particles can't be in two places at once. If this turned out to be true would this mean that it is impossible to build a quantum computer. As quantum computers rely on a qubit being in two places at once?

Comment: But (without specifically endorsing the pilot wave view of things) the *wave* can be in two places at once, and it is the wave (and the combination of them from multiple sources) that the particle follows.

Comment: Since quantum computers have already been built, I'd say they are safe enough from the "implications". In other words, any alternative interpretation of quantum mechanics shouldn't go against experimental facts

Comment: the pilot wave  theory , bohmian mechanics, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_wave ) gives the exact same predictions for non relativistic quantum mechanics, so there can be no problem.  I do not think  quantum computers work at relativistic energies, so there would be no problem.

Comment: Moose, I'd just say moreover on this subject generally (not specifically on the Bohmian view), it's not entirely clear whether the "particle" has any physical reality. In other words, it is a shorthand for a net *transfer of* energy. The wave is the carrier of the transfer, but the transfer itself is not a physical object, and it's easier to understand how the whole thing reconciles itself (and "knows" which path to take) if you postulate the existence of a contra-wave in the opposite direction from the receiver (which simultaneously carries the contra for the transfer back to the source).

Answer (score -1):

First off, quantum computing requires particles to be in 2 states at once, not 2 locations.
Second, as far as I understand (and I am not an expert in the field) the mechanics behind quantum computing should still work as long as quantum entanglement exists, which it certainly does in Bohmian Mechanics.

Comment: I don't think quantum entanglement is a requirement but a quantum superposition of states is.

Comment: Brad S, check out this link: https://phys.org/news/2016-09-quantum-advances-entanglement.html